# How do I access XML data in python?

Tags: python, json, xml, api

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


user = "deletedforpost"
passw = "deletedforpost"

request = requests.get('https://api.intrinio.com/press_releases?identifier=TSLA', auth=(user, passw)).json()

request = request['data']

url_List = []
    for element in request:
    url_List.append(element['url'])
print(url_List)
```

I added basically bunch of different XML urls into the list url_List.
What I want to do now is access their content. What should I do?
I am still very new to this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: for element in request:
    url_List.append(element['url']) - This line added basically all the values of the key 'url' into the list url_List. These values look like this: https://s3.amazonaws.com/intrinio-data/NASDAQ/press-releases/201708021615NASDAQ__NDE______6921968_en.xml

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `bs4`, you can do something like this:

```
data_List = []
for url in url_List:
    content = requests.get(url).text
    data_List.append(BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml-xml'))
```

This will put all your `xml` parsed content into the `data_List`, you could also create a dictionary with keys being the url and values it's associated `BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml-xml')`.

Comment: Hi, I tried it and got following error: "Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml-xml. Do you need to install a parser library?"

Comment: You *do* need to install a parser library, you have to install `lxml`, a simple `pip install lxml` should do.